# Альтернатива cellspacing и cellpadding в свойстве style

Tags: style, html

Приветствую всех

Есть ли альтернатива `cellspacing` и `cellpadding` в свойстве `style`? Не что либо прописанное в `css`, а именно в свойстве `style`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простите, а чем отличается прописанное в CSS от прописанного в style? :)

Используйте все те же

```
border-collapse
border-spacing
```

только в свойстве style элемента. Эффект будет тот же :)

Comment: Извиняюсь. Что то я тупанул 8-)